# increase width of the button spinner in numericUpDown in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, toolkit, numericupdown

I am just getting started with WPF, and now uses this [NumericUpDown control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=NumericUpDown-derived%20controls) from the Extended WPF Toolkit. However, the [ButtonSpinners](http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download?ProjectName=wpftoolkit&DownloadId=222922) are very thin in my app and I haven't found any property to change it. Anyway to increase the width?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you [make your own](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509824/Creating-a-NumericUpDown-control-from-scratch)?  Or perhaps [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267601/Csharp-WPF-NET-ArrowRepeatButton-NumericUpDown) will give you a hint

Answer (score 0):

There exists a property for that: `ButtonSpinnerWidth`

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Count}" 
                    Width="150"
                    Height="100"
                    Margin="8" 
                    Padding="0 0 15 0"
                    ButtonSpinnerWidth="100"/>
```

So you get something like that:

[image]

Found that Property in a Binding in the Template:

> “mouse right click” -> “Edit Template” -> “Edit a copy”

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/2bf227ed-7c6e-4517-9019-54eb8fce6bf7/how-to-incrase-tough-target-size-for-updown-arrows-of-a-integerupdown-control-in-the-wpf-toolkit?forum=wpf